# Lifetime of a game purchased from PlayStation Store for PS4

Tags: ps4

I have a question regarding the longevity of the game when purchased from PlayStation Store.

If you buy the disk version of the game you can play it years after the game is purchased as long as the disk is in good condition.

I wanted to know if the game, once purchased from PlayStation Store, will be available after few years for download and be playable?

Eg: GTA-5 game disk version can be played even after 5-7 years if the disk is in good condition.

If I buy a digital copy of GTA-5 from PlayStation Store, will I be able to download the game after 5-7 years and play it?

Comment: I would imagine so. These purchases would be linked to your PSstore account, correct?

Comment: We are not Sony and we are not psychic. We have no way of knowing whether Sony will keep their games available in the future.

Comment: When you click the "Buy" button to buy a game from a digital distribution platform, you're sometimes not really buying the game.  You're sometimes just renting it.  Your rental expires when the digital distribution platform is closed down.

Comment: For what it's worth, I feel this is a rather important question that needs to be asked (and not just about Sony's digital distribution platform)... but not *here*. This is far to speculative a question to fit our strict Q&A format. Does [digital distribution platform] have plans for the longevity of the software we are paying for? If they do, when the current system reaches its end-of-life, will those plans be followed through? We, unfortunately, have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Texenox yes the game would be linked to my PSstore Account.

Answer (score 3):

Until Sony decides to stop supporting it, however long that may be.

You can download the game only as long as there are servers to download it from, there are no requirements for Sony to keep hosting these servers indefinitely.

You *may* be able to play the game after the servers stop working in offline mode, *if* you have already downloaded it before hand, but that is unlikely to work for more than a few days before the console tries to phone home to check if you are allowed to run the game and receives no response.

Comment: +1, but I'd note that there is no guarantee your purchase of GTA5 in this case will be playable on *future* Playstation platforms.

Comment: While that is true, seems a bit unrelated to the question being asked to me. I mean, the disc won't work in a different platform either.

Comment: That's true, but there was a bit of a surprise felt by some people when PSNow (the PS4's streaming system for PS3 games) didn't automatically grant you access to games you owned digitally. Just trying to cover all the bases.